Not expected yarn.lock content changed after yarn install
Check details in the img bellow. The left is master branch and right is my local dev branch.
The difference is not expect since changes in package.json does not contain those npm packages.
Why cause this difference and how to fix it?
My local env:
MacOS: 14.5
Node: 20.16
yarn: 1.22.22
yarn-deduplicate: 6.0.2

